# How To Display Certain Text In A Shared Div According To The Different Pages The Javascript Is On?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innerhtml

I am new here. And I am working on a webcomic layout script. I want to show the page's info (Chapter #, Page #, Chapter Title, etc.) on the designated pages. An example is--

If the visitor is on page two of the comic I want it to say something like this:

Chapter #01: The Start-Up | Page #02 - Comic #002 (Nov.28.2023)

```
<div id="comicInfo">
<div id="ch"></div>
<div id="pg"></div>
<div id="comno"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe the code will be something like:

```
if (document.URL.includes("comics/page001.htm") ) {
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = "Chapter #01: The Start-Up";
document.getElementById("pg").innerHTML = "Page #01";
document.getElementById("comno").innerHTML = "Comic #001";

} else if (document.URL.includes("comics/page002.htm") ) {
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = "Chapter #01: The Start-Up";
document.getElementById("pg").innerHTML = "Page #02";
document.getElementById("comno").innerHTML = "Comic #002";

} else if (document.URL.includes("comics/page003.htm") ) {
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = "Chapter #01: The Start-Up";
document.getElementById("pg").innerHTML = "Page #03";
document.getElementById("comno").innerHTML = "Comic #003";
}

else (document.URL.includes("comics/page004.htm") ) {
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = "Chapter #01: The Start-Up";
document.getElementById("pg").innerHTML = "Page #04";
document.getElementById("comno").innerHTML = "Comic #004";
}
```

I would appreciate the help.

I tried the above code and couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *At a glance*... You have a syntax error which is being reported in your browser's development console.  (Always check there for errors.)  Your `else` block includes a condition as though it were an `else if` block.